# bundle installでエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby, bundler

あるrubyアプリケーションをインストールしようとしています。`bundle install`を実行すると以下のようなエラーが発生し、インストールを行えません。

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)

    activeadmin was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
```

`bundle update`も試してみたのですが、同様のエラー（以下）が出て実行できません。

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)

    activeadmin was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
```

どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このエラーは、「Gemfile内ではjquery-railsのバージョン3.0.4を指定しているけど、activeadmin gemはjquery-railsのバージョン4.2以上5.0未満を指定(`~> 4.2`のことです)しているから、その両方を満たすバージョンがありません」と言っています。

次のようなGemfileで同じようなエラーを再現できます。

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jquery-rails', '= 3.0.4'
gem 'activeadmin', '= 2.4.0'
```

```sh
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)

    activeadmin (= 2.4.0) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
```

この場合、jquery-railsのバージョン固定を外すことで問題を回避できます。

↑のGemfileであれば次のように編集することでこのエラーを回避することができます。

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jquery-rails' # '= 3.0.4' を削除
gem 'activeadmin', '= 2.4.0'
```

jquery-rails のバージョンを固定する必要がないのであれば、バージョン指定を外してみると良いと思います。